# common www folder and all files for all platform in cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

I have 2 copies for my work in cordova since last 2 years and it's working without any error.

1. For android/ios
2. Windows phone

in both copies of there only platform specific changes are there. Means in windows phone it can't allow to load out html files so i add all html files in script tag and load in to main index.html for make thing working and it's working in windows phone and in 2nd copy i made normal html files separate as android and ios has no issue with load outer html files.

**so my question:** Is there any way to merge all code in one single copy and with same www folder code will work in android,ios and windows phone as well ?

May be it's not possible as per i go through becuase windows phone has some different file structure then android/ios.

Please guide if any one know some common work around for all platforms.

Comment: No you can't do that you need to work independent with each platform. What currently you are doing is only the way.

Comment: thanks @jaydroider for your feedback but i can wait for some other suggestions also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "merges" feature in Cordova CLI to do this.  Imagine I have a project that looks like this:

`-rw-r--r--  1 simon  staff  1115 Mar 22 19:57 config.xml
drwxr-xr-x  3 simon  staff   102 Mar 17 21:47 hooks/
drwxr-xr-x  7 simon  staff   238 Mar 22 19:57 platforms/
drwxr-xr-x  7 simon  staff   238 Mar 22 19:57 plugins/
drwxr-xr-x  7 simon  staff   238 Mar 21 13:11 www/`

With my application code all in www, organized like this:

`drwxr-xr-x  4 simon  staff   136 Mar 24 12:42 css/
drwxr-xr-x  4 simon  staff   136 Mar 21 13:11 img/
-rw-r--r--  1 simon  staff  1338 Mar 21 15:16 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  4 simon  staff   136 Mar 22 18:29 js/`

Imagine I have both the Android and iOS platforms installed, and want to do something different on each, without putting lots of:

`if (device.platform === 'Android') {
  // Android specific code
} else {
  // iOS specific, assuming we are only supporting iOS
}`

sort of code in my application.  That also doesn't scale to many platforms (eg add Windows and BB in there and then you have more if/else or a switch statement every time).

To help with this, Cordova's CLI can merge code in, and will look for a top level folder called merges.  So make one of those in the same folder your config.xml is in, so project now looks like:

`-rw-r--r--  1 simon  staff  1115 Mar 22 19:57 config.xml
drwxr-xr-x  3 simon  staff   102 Mar 17 21:47 hooks/
drwxr-xr-x  4 simon  staff   136 Mar 22 17:47 merges/
drwxr-xr-x  7 simon  staff   238 Mar 22 19:57 platforms/
drwxr-xr-x  7 simon  staff   238 Mar 22 19:57 plugins/
drwxr-xr-x  7 simon  staff   238 Mar 21 13:11 www/`

Then create:

`merges/android
merges/ios`

Anything you put in there will get copied into the platform specific www folder and override stuff in the same path from your main www folder, or be added if there's nothing of same name/path in www.

Example:

`ls -lF merges/android/img
total 16
-rw-------@ 1 simon  staff  7626 Mar 21 13:23 logo.png`

This image logo.png will replace www/img/logo.png for Android only.  I can either do the same for iOS (add merges/ios/img/logo.png) or have that use the default image (www/img/logo.png).

This can be done for any type of file (JS/CSS/img/JSON/whatever) that you need on a platform specific basis.

There's no need to write a hook script to make this work, the CLI does it automatically when you run cordova build for each platform.

Documentation on this concept is in the [Cordova CLI docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#using-merges-to-customize-each-platform).

Comment: hi @simon thanks for your answer, But i have question, If i change cordova root 'www' folder any files will it not impact directly for all paltforms ? measn i have to change all platform specific changes in merges/related-platforms.. I need to do change in main www folder's file of cordova will impact for all platforms. I want my code as single copy for all platfomrs. i can do in filter for platforms in java script with device.platform but it will work for android and ios only will it work for wp8 also? Thank you

Comment: Yes, anything you change in `www` (folder in same folder as `config.xml`) will get pushed down to the `www` folder for each platform in your project (`platforms/ios/...`, `platforms/android/...` etc).  To do platform specific stuff use merges as described as you should treat the `platforms` folder as a build artifact and should not be having stuff in there that's checked into source control.  The method I describe works for all platforms Cordova supports because it's a feature of the Cordova CLI.

Comment: but cordova android/ios has different file structure then wp8 so will it work if i change any platform specific  changes? Means android/ios works fine together but will wp8 work with android/ios file structure? if yes, can you please provide any example for it. thank you

Comment: Your application (inside `www`) should have the same structure for each platform.  Cordova's CLI knows where the platform specific `www` folder is for each platform and will ensure that the result of merging your `www` with anything in `merges/<platform name>` will end up in the right place.

Comment: ok will try as you suggested and will ping you back soon. Thank you for feedback